# Highcharts pie chart with expand area

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I need to build pie chart, which can be expand like in picture:
[chart example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gc0wP.png). It would be perfect if it's made with highcharts but if it's impossible it's ok. I have tried to do that with pie chart plus donut pie chart, and hide some parts of higher level data but it's not working well. Is there any solution to do that? All I want is some clue or tip, where to look for solution.

Comment: You can use donut chart http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-donut

Comment: I have tried that but there is a lot of problems with that. It's hard to hide specific series and their tooltip or labels. There is also problem with refreshing chart, it's refreshing only after mouse move on series. That's why I'm looking for something different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to add series that will change size on point click in main pie.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/vkhvvs5d/

```
...
        point: {
            events: {
                click: function () {
                    var chart = this.series.chart,
                        series = chart.series,
                        len = series.length,
                        index = this.x + 1,
                        i;
                    for (i = 1; i < len; i++) {
                        if (i === index) {
                            series[i].update({
                                size: '100%',
                                dataLabels: {
                                    enabled: true
                                }
                            }, false);
                        } else {
                            series[i].update({
                                size: '0%',
                                dataLabels: {
                                    enabled: false
                                }
                            }, false);
                        }
                    }
                    chart.redraw();
                }
            }
        },
...
```